# Is a continuous locally square-integrable martingale uniquely (in distribution) determined by its angle bracket?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, martingales, stochastic-analysis

**Question:** Given a real-valued continuous increasing predictable process $A$, is there a real-valued continuous locally square-integrable martingale $M$, such that $\langle M\rangle = A$ ? If so, is this $M$ unique in distribution, that is, if there is an $N$ fulfill the assumption, then $M$ and $N$ has the same law in the path space ?

The angle bracket $\langle M\rangle$ denotes the [predictable quadratic variation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_variation#Martingales) of $M$, that is, the unique continuous increasing predictable process starting at zero such that $M^2 − \langle M\rangle$ is a local martingale.

**Motivation:** This question arises when I was reading the [book of J. Jacod & A. N. Shiryaev](https://books.google.pt/books?hl=en&lr=&id=mSD4CAAAQBAJ&oi=fnd&pg=PA1&dq=Limit%20Theorems%20for%20Stochastic%20Processes&ots=3hVmWwJSMr&sig=UtmWIs7-ocoMYX97TXdNvq9WEeo&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=Limit%20Theorems%20for%20Stochastic%20Processes&f=false). They define the characteristics of semimartingales in Section II.2. Given a truncation function $h$, the characteristics of a semimartingale $X$ associated with $h$ is a unique triplet $(B,C,\nu)$. So a natural question is: can a triplet $(B,C,\nu)$ for a fixed truncation function $h$ determine a semimartingale uniquely in the sense of distribution? The begining question is a special case and part of this question.

**Part of the answer:** If the increasing process $A=\{A_t\}_{t\ge0}$ in the question is an absolutely continuous function of $t$ a.s., then the [martingale representation theorem](https://books.google.pt/books?id=w0SgBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA170&dq=A.%20Continuous%20Local%20Martingales%20and%20Stochastic%20Integrals%20Let%20us%20recall&hl=zh-CN&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjsz_aij4HvAhVLxYUKHdmvBikQ6AEwAHoECAQQAg#v=onepage&q=A.%20Continuous%20Local%20Martingales%20and%20Stochastic%20Integrals%20Let%20us%20recall&f=false) asserts that there is a stochastic integral with respect to a Brownian motion such that the angle bracket of this stochastic integral is $A$.

Comment: More generally this question is addressed in the introduction of the Chapter III in connection with martingale problems. Theorem II.2.21 tells that a process X is a semimartingale with characteristics $(B, C, \nu)$ if certain processes are local martingales (i.e. question is reformulated as a martingale problem), and the solution must not be unique for general semimartingales (i.e. processes given in II.2.21 are local martingales under several measures, hence different in law).

Comment: @nakajuice Thank you for the mention of Theorem II.2.21. But I feel that this theorem says nothing to the uniqueness. For the special case that $X=M$ with $M$ the martingale in my begining question, the triplet of $X$ is $(0,A,0)$. So Theorem II.2.21 reduces to that $X$ is a semimartingale with triplet $(0,A,0)$ iff $X^2-\langle X\rangle$ is a local martingale, which is just the definition of angle bracket.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can let $B$ be a Brownian motion and set $M_t = B_{A_t}$.  You need to be a bit careful about the filtrations to make that work, but that can be handled if you look at the proofs about continuous martingales as time changed Brownian motion.  I'm not sure whether or not this is unique in distribution, though.

Edit: This $M$ is not unique.  Let $B_t$ be a Brownian motion, set $\tau := \inf\{t : B_t = -1\}$, and let $A_t := t \wedge \tau$.  The processes $M_t := B_{t \wedge \tau}$ and $N_t := - B_{t \wedge \tau}$ are both continuous locally square integrable martingales with $\langle M \rangle_t = \langle N \rangle_t = t \wedge \tau = A_t$, but $\mathbb{P}(M_t < -1) = 0$ and $\mathbb{P}(N_t < -1) > 0$.

Comment: This will work if $B$ is independent of $A$.

Comment: Thank you. This is another way of martingale representation, than the way to represent as a stochastic integral. But what I am really concerned is the uniqueness, as I said in the motivation part.

Comment: Yes, it is another martingale representation, but I don't think mine requires absolute continuity?  You mentioning that drawback made it seem like you were still looking for a further answer there.  Nonetheless, I added a non-uniqueness proof.

Comment: Thank you very much. That is a good example. Basically, $\langle M \rangle = \langle -M \rangle$ but $M$ and $-M$ may not equal in distribution. So can we say that the local martingale determined by $A$ is unique in distribution and up to a sign?

Comment: I'm not sure about that.  I think we could keep reflecting one of them every time it hits a certain threshold to get another process with the same quadratic variation, but a completely different distribution even ignoring the sign.